# ERROR on Custom Validation in c#

Tags: c#

Error is:

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Function of Custom Validator:

```
protected void chkdate1(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    IFormatProvider theCultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", true);
    DateTime from = DateTime.ParseExact(txt_from_date.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", theCultureInfo);
    DateTime to = DateTime.ParseExact(txt_to_date.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", theCultureInfo);
}
```

Custom Validation is:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="scdt1" runat="server" OnServerValidate="chkdate1" ErrorMessage="To date not less than From date">
```

Comment: What is in txt_From_date and txt_to_date?

Comment: there is todate and from date in both textboxes. it stores only date in M/d/yyyy formate.

Answer (score 0):

For the `DateTime.ParseExact()`, The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly  or an exception is thrown.
Why can't you try to parse with `DateTime.Parse()` method or `DateTime.TryParseExact()` method

Answer (score 0):

Probably the reason you are getting this error is that the date you are passing doesn't contain time. It should be like the following format:

```
"06/27/2012 12:00:00"
```

Or you may use different format if your txt_from_date doesn't contain time.

```
DateTime from = DateTime.ParseExact(txt_from_date, "MM/dd/yyyy", theCultureInfo);
```

EDIT: Based on comments

```
DateTime from = DateTime.ParseExact(txt_from_date, "M/d/yyyy", theCultureInfo);
DateTime to = DateTime.ParseExact(txt_to_date.Text, "M/d/yyyy", theCultureInfo);
```

Since you mentioned your date format as `M/d/yyyy`, you should specify that in your DateTime.ParseExact

Comment: but sir, i have a textboxes that stores only date not with time.

Comment: your dateFormat is "M/d/yyyy" you should specify this in format

Comment: thanks. but when the todate<fromdate i want to set todate textbox becomes null.

Comment: If you are not getting any error now, you may check `if(to < from) { txt_to_date.Text = string.Empty; }`

Comment: Dear sir, i got both value in to_date and From_date but when compare int result = DateTime.Compare(to, from);
            e.IsValid = result>0;
            if (e.IsValid == false)
            {
                txt_to_date.Text = "";
                txt_to_date.Focus();
            } it excution next goes to button click event that i not want it goes if and only if it true. if false then goes to txt_to date to select new date.

Comment: @MiteshMachhi, that is a new question, if you have find solution to your current question, you may post a new question for the new problem